# Creating Temporary array to keep calculations in r

Tags: r

I want the value 0.01 appended to a temporary array until the age reaches 30 for the each probability `in the Dataframe called Data` to be used in a formula calculation. For instance for the first line in the data frame Age =21, so I’d like to create a temporary array that looks like this for each entry based on their age and probability.

```
x = c(.21,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01)
Data2 = data.frame(x)
```

Then I use this in the formula below:

```
for (i in 1:length(Data$Prob))
{
    for (j in 1:length(Data2$x)) {
         Data$NPV[i] = sum(x[j]*CostofFailure[i]*0.025)/(1+0.07)^j)
}
}


  **Dataframe: Data**
  Age  Prob    Cost      NPV 
  21     45       4000     
  24     21       2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using rep function if you need to create a vector by appending a particular value n number of times to another chosen value, say .21.

```
x = c(.21,rep(0.01,30-21))
```

Will yield the result,

```
[1] 0.21 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
```